# How to interpolate current path in eshell

Tags: eshell

In eshell when I do

```
$ echo "$(pwd)credentials.json"
Directory /Users/gmauer/../credentials.json
```

I get that `Directory` prefix. I'm assuming that it is because eshell reimplements pwd to return some sort of object, and `Directory ....` is how that is being coerced into  a string.

So how do I interpolate this correctly so that I can use export it to an environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the environment variable `PWD`, e.g.,

```
~/.emacs.d $ export CREDIT="$PWD/credentials.json"
~/.emacs.d $ echo $CREDIT
/Users/xcy/.emacs.d/credentials.json
```

When you type `pwd` in Eshell

```
~/.emacs.d $ pwd
```

Eshell tries to execute one of the following (the order matters)

1. The lisp function `eshell/pwd`
2. The executable file `pwd` in your `PATH`
3. The lisp function `pwd`

When you use `(pwd)` in your Eshell

```
$ echo "$(pwd)credentials.json"
Directory /Users/gmauer/../credentials.json
```

the lisp function `pwd` will be used, and the function `pwd` is for showing current working directory in the Echo Area. You should use `eshell/pwd` instead

```
~/.emacs.d $ echo "$(eshell/pwd)/credentials.json"
/Users/xcy/.emacs.d/credentials.json
```